# How can I show data which is greater than or equal to mysql table column month?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 columns (there are more) in `clients` table.

```
conn_date     bill_date
=======================
2016-08-25    2016-09-04
2016-08-01    2016-09-03
2016-08-08    2016-09-01
2016-08-09    2016-09-01
```

Now I want to show all data if selected month is = (equal) or > greater then `conn_date`. I can get selected month from html select tag e. g. : 1, 2, 9.

For that purpose, I am using following query but it's showing data less than `conn_date`

```
"SELECT cbp.advance_amount, cbp.bill_month, cbp.due_amount, cbp.pay_amount, c.is_active, c.client_id, c.user_id, c.address, c.contact_no, zone.zone_name, package.package_name, c.monthly_bill, c.bill_date FROM clients 
AS c LEFT JOIN zone ON zone.zone_id = c.zone_id 
LEFT JOIN package ON package.package_id = c.package_id 
LEFT JOIN clients_pay_bill AS cbp ON cbp.client_id = c.client_id 
WHERE c.uid = '$uid' AND c.is_active = 1 
AND MONTH(c.conn_date) > $selected_month
```

**Using print_r**

```
SELECT cbp.advance_amount, cbp.bill_month, cbp.due_amount, cbp.pay_amount,
c.is_active, c.client_id, c.user_id, c.address, c.contact_no, zone.zone_name, package.package_name, c.monthly_bill, c.bill_date 
FROM clients AS c 
LEFT JOIN zone ON zone.zone_id = c.zone_id 
LEFT JOIN package ON package.package_id = c.package_id 
LEFT JOIN clients_pay_bill AS cbp ON cbp.client_id = c.client_id 
WHERE c.uid = '6' AND c.is_active = 1 
AND MONTH(c.conn_date) > 4 AND c.zone_id != '' 
ORDER BY c.client_id DESC
```

**Selected Month Image**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically, I want to show data which is not less than conn_date of selected month

The mysql query for that is

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE MONTH(conn_date)<='".$selected_month."'
```

Comment: but not less than conn_date month value

Comment: Exactly. conn_date(Not less) >(Than) $selected_month. Just making sure that we speak same language, less means smaller/littler/tiny for you?

Comment: Sorry my misunderstanding.. It will be show data only if selected month is equal to conn_date month or greater than conn_date month NOT selected date less than conn_date month.

Comment: Glad to hear, accept as a answer if this solved your problem

Comment: Can I add one more condition ? Data will not show if select month is greater than current month

Answer (score 0):

From the description of your problem, it sounds like you want:

```
select c.*
from clients c
where conn_date >= str_to_date(concat(date_format(now(), '%Y-%m'), '-01'))
```

This returns dates greater than the current time.  If you want a particular month of a particular year:

```
select c.*
from clients c
where conn_date >= str_to_date(concat_ws('-', $year, $month, '01'))
```

I am not sure what your query does, because it uses several tables not mentioned in the question.

Comment: I have updated my question. I added how the actual query is running. Basically, I want to show data which is not less than `conn_date` of selected month.